# En una consulta de SQL, como puedo generar una tabla auxiliar para guardar un dato calculado de la misma consulta?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Digamos que tengo solo una tabla, en la cual figura solo el nombre de un articulo, el precio y la cantidad existente.

Y quiero ejecutar una consulta para obtener todos los datos, pero también el valor total de cada uno (Precio * cantidad existente).

```
SELECT * FROM tablaProductos;
```

Ese seria lo normal, pero como hago para que se muestre también el producto en cuestión?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y porque lo queres poner en otra tabla? sabias que en la misma consulta podes hacer operaciones con los campos y generar nuevos campos?

Comment: Me puede dar un ejemplo?, es a lo que me refiero, como genero ese nuevo campo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select nombre, cantidad, precio, cantidad * precio as "valor total"
from tabla;
```

Haces una consulta donde vas a seleccionar los campos que desees y vas a incorporar la multiplicación de la cantidad con el precio del artículo y a ese campo le vas a dar como **alias "valor total"**, para eso es el **comando as**. En la **cláusula select** puedes hacer cualquier proyección de datos que desees, combinando datos de la tabla, uniendo datos de la tabla, etcétera.

Comment: Ha funcionado, gracias. Una disculpa si no redacto bien mis preguntas, soy nuevo.

Comment: @DanielRosas, si te funciono te agradecería que marcara la respuesta como aceptada y dieras un voto, gracias